# Missing departement in user profile

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, central-administration, ad

I have a user whose account does not display department in the user list in a site SharePoint 2010. For example, **user2's departement** does not appear in the list. But this departement information displays in another site SharePoint 2010 in the same web application.

The differents is one site uses the template in English (does not display Departement), and another site uses the template in French (display Departement)
[image]

I had checked his account in AD, all information is right. I know user profile synchronizes with AD, I don't understand why this department information does not synchronize with the English site

Comment: what permission level of user 2 in the site where no department information displayed? is user profile sync service is running?

Answer (score 0):

Profiles are first imported via User Profile Synchronization which is part of the User Profile Service Application. Then, a scheduled timer job is supposed to sync the latest updated profile data to each site collection.

Each site collection stores a copy of the user profile information in it's User list. I believe if a user logs in and the user's profile information is not in the user list, it is added to the list with data pulled from the Service App profile database or AD.

You can manually run the "stsadm -o sync" command to tell SharePoint to run the synchronization script that synchronizes the site collection user list data with the user profile data from the shared services provider.

Note: If you continue to have issues, it is possible to delete the individual user's profile information for the particular site. However, not recommended.

Comment: Don't delete the user info. If the user is "active" on the site (like adding a document or list item) the timer will sync their info.